# Use a label or tag system instead of a path system for Windows files

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

Is there any way to use a label or tag system (like Gmail) instead of the path system (Explorer) that Windows 7 uses?

I have files that I want to be able to find from multiple directories without using shortcuts (they tend to break easily).

## UPDATE

I know this might be new thinking and not working with windows at all, but my "dream" would be an explorer like this:

[image: Example]

Here you can write (or select by the mouse) the tags and then the explorer will shows the files that contain these tags. Below the selected tags it will show the non-selected tags that the files also contains and the number of files which contain these tags.

You can save you favorit tags or bundle of tags (like a directory shortcut)

Hope it all makes sense.

Comment: Windows search?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on that? What kind of shortcuts? You mean shortcuts to files and folders?... the icons with an arrow in the bottom left corner? They won't break unless you move the files and folders around. Or if you make your shortcuts relative.

Comment: If I have buried a file deep within a directory and change the name of one of the folders in that directory path, then all my shortcuts dies.

Comment: I mean both files and folders

Comment: If that's what you want, then the answer is no. That doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

Windows 7 has libraries that do just that.

Right click on any folder, choose **Include in library** and either add it to an existing library (*Documents, Music, Pictures, or Videos*) or create one of your own (*Create new library*). The library function is present in every Save/Open dialog box in Windows, unless the program uses its own dialog box.

[image: a]

Comment: This will work like one-tag/label solution - I kinda want a multiple labe/tag solution and what if the files are on a shared drive then all the other users wont see the files?